# Tomcat doesn't log an error but I've got Internal Server Error on the web

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I have a java web app hosted on Ubuntu AWS. I am using `Apache Tomcat v7` for deploying Java apps.

When I am doing heavy process (reading big xlsx file and making a JSON out of it), the app returns me `Internal Server Error` on the browser.

I wanted to investigate what the error was so I have opened `conf/catalina.out` where output of the app is and this is a part of what I get:

```
 - Sync is not success yet.
Done importing one batch!
Importing a batch:49000
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
Done importing one batch!
Importing a batch:49000
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
 - Sync is not success yet.
```

There is nothing wrong with the output, that is what I expect, except the thing that it doesn't show any error, neither program finished output.

What I was thinking, it might be that I am catching an exception somewhere. I will have to check it, but I am pretty sure that I am printing out the error.

Comment: can it be related to a timeout exception?

Comment: I think the default timeout in tomcat is 30 minutes and my app is loading only about 1-3 minutes.

Comment: are yuo using some logging framewor? like logback or log4j? Did you check if you write exception in other files and your log ystem configuration?

Comment: No I am not using anything. For printing the exceptions out I use ex.printStackTrace() method.

Comment: when you talk about creating JSON and so on... are you using an AJAX call? If so... by using firebug may you check the answer returned from server? maybe you can copy it on a html file and check what is returned

Comment: No I am not, I would definitely use firebug. But no, all the process is done on Java.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that was, that `catalina.out` was still being updated, server was still appending info about the job, quite long time after the job has crushed. So I couldn't see the real reason of crashing.